# How to create an anvil / coat of arms shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: anvil]

How can the above shape be created in Photoshop?  It is the shape of an anvil, a logo commonly used by universities.

Comment: Of course it would make sense for you to learn how to do that yourself, but if my memmory doesn't fail me, there is some short of shield shape for Shape tool in photoshop ( not sure if it's exactly like your example). You just need to append it from one of the shape packages in the tool menu.

Comment: Nope, not under the Shape tool. Seem to be a manual effort required to draw this. Check the Pen tool. This will allow you to make nice curves.

Comment: @AbdiasSoftware In the Shape list: "Symbols". In that package there are 3 of these http://i.stack.imgur.com/FPtFP.png though not quite the same, as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pen tool. There's only five points there, it won't take long. The only point that will require curve handles is the bottom point.

For speed and accuracy of drawing, here's the path I would take:

- draw a vector rectangle
- add the fifth point to the middle of the bottom side
- move it down to roughly the right spot
- drag out the handles once you have the extra point positioned